# C# IDisposable object for entire class

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-reuse, using-statement

The project that I'm working on at the moment uses an IDisposable object in every method in a class. It has started getting tedious re-typing the using block at the start of every method, and was wondering if there was a way to specify a disposable variable for use in every method of the class?

```
public static class ResourceItemRepository
{
    public static ResourceItem GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var db = DataContextFactory.Create<TestDataContext>())
        {
            // Code goes here...
        }
    }
    public static List<ResourceItem> GetInCateogry(int catId)
    {
        using (var db = DataContextFactory.Create<TestDataContext>())
        {
            // Code goes here...
        }
    }
    public static ResourceItem.Type GetType(int id)
    {
        using (var db = DataContextFactory.Create<TestDataContext>())
        {
            // Code goes here...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there's nothing particularly geared towards this. You *could* write:

```
public static ResourceItem GetById(int id)
{
    WithDataContext(db =>
    {
        // Code goes here...
    });
}

// Other methods here, all using WithDataContext

// Now the only method with a using statement:
private static T WithDataContext<T>(Func<TestDataContext, T> function)
{
    using (var db = DataContextFactory.Create<TestDataContext>())
    {
        return function(db);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that it would be *particularly* beneficial though.

(Note that I've had to change it from `Action<TestDataContext>` in my original version to `Func<TestDataContext, T>` as you want to be able to return values from your methods.)

Comment: I have learned something from your reply - have been trying to get my head around lambda expressions and using them in the real world. Thanks.

Comment: Nice solution... Only question would be how to make it easier to unit test... I've used IOC to inject the context factory, so I guess I answered my own question...

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, i'd keep the verbose code, but using a snippet instead of typing it all each time.
Either create your own snippet with a [special tool](http://snippy.codeplex.com/) or use text-replacement tools like [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple refactoring is the best that you can do without resorting to something like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/):

```
public static class ResourceItemRepository {
  public static ResourceItem GetById(int id) {
    using (var db = CreateDataContext()) {
      // Code goes here... 
    }
  }
  public static List<ResourceItem> GetInCateogry(int catId) {
    using (var db = CreateDataContext()) {
      // Code goes here... 
    }
  }
  public static ResourceItem.Type GetType(int id) {
    using (var db = CreateDataContext()) {
      // Code goes here... 
    }
  }
  private static TestDataContext CreateDataContext() {
    return DataContextFactory.Create<TestDataContext>();
  }
}
```